# Multi key layered encryption verification

Tags: encryption, keys, certificates

Is it possible to take some value text like “Hello World!” And encrypt it with a random key. Then take the encrypted message and encrypt it again with another random key. And so on…

Then can you write a function that takes in the final encrypted message plus any one of the keys from before and return True or False. With True being: the key was used to encrypt the message. And False being: the key was not used to encrypt the message.

If this is possible. Could you point me in the right direction of what style of cryptography this is.
Thanks :)

Comment: I assume you want it to be the case that the ciphertext can only be decrypted with knowledge of all keys? You could just append a list of the hashes of every key used to encrypt.

Comment: Not exactly. I want it to be encrypted with multiple keys and then allow it to be decrypted by one key. But that key can be any one of the encryption keys.